# Access User Properties within workflow in Visual Studio

Tags: workflow, office-365, user-profile-property, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to access User Properties from within the workflow designer for Visual Studio.

I've gotten as far as getting the User's ID, and then looking them up.

My problem is that fields such as manager and department are not accessible within the properties for the GetDynamicValueProperties of that user.

My searches so far have only shown Sharepoint2010 which allows code-behind (I'm making this for O365), or sharepoint designer, which seems to have all of the properties available.
I'm making an app for sharepoint in visual studio though, so I believe sharepoint designer is out of the question.

Is something along the lines of __metadata/department what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage `HttpSend` activity by consuming [SharePoint User Profile REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800(v=office.15).aspx) to return specific user profile properties like `Department`.

[image]

Assume we need to retrieve current user `Department` property.

1) Add `HttpSend` activity and specify its properties:

- `Method`: `GET`
- `Uri`:
  `string.Format("{0}/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",WebUrl)`
- `ResponseContent`: save result into `MyPropertiesData` variable. `WebUrl` variable stores current Web Url.

2) Then add `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity to extract `Department` property from result variable `MyPropertiesData` and specify its properties:

- `Source`: `MyPropertiesData`
- In Properties dialog enter `d/Department` path and assign it to
  `Department` variable

### References

- [Working with Web Services in SharePoint 2013 Workflows using Visual
  Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn532193(v=office.15).aspx)
- [Work with user profiles in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: WebUrl is the string returned by the WebUri activity, no?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me, but that is probably due to permissions or something; I'm marking your response as an answer due to it not working being most likely through my own inadequacy.

Comment: I could verify it (permissions and etc.) and get back to you, but some later today.

Comment: That would be amazing; sharepoint's workflows are making me tear my hair out. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Yeah, i understand what you mean, developing SharePoint Workflows in Visual Studio sometimes could be a nightmare..